# PSD file with same measurements as InDesign document appears larger when placed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign

I have a 300dpi layered `.psd` file with the exact same measurements as the InDesign document (`14.525 x 11` including bleed).

When I place/import the `.psd` file into InDesign the file appears larger.

The guides on the `.psd` file do not line up with the guides in the InDesign document which are in the exact same positions on both files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happen if you print a proof, how it looks?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you're not correctly allowing for bleed. Two possibilities:

- The PSD is the size of the document without the bleed, or the INDD is of the dimensions you give instead of being that size minus bleed.
- InDesign's document size doesn't include the bleed, so a guide placed at 1 inch from an edge is 1 inch from the *trim* edge, not from the *bleed*. A guide that is 1 inch from that same edge in Photoshop wouldn't line up with the InDesign guide; it would be off by the width of the bleed.

(Another possibility, if there is no typo in your question, is that your PSD should be 14.625 inches (14-5/8th) rather than 14.525.)